# uninitialized constant ApplicationController::CanCan (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, cancan

My application runs normally on development environment but I am getting the following error when I try to run > `rails server -e production`
I have searched for this and I found answers about restarting unicorn but I don't have unicorn in my application, what can I do to fix it ?

```
/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6:in `<class:ApplicationController>': uninitialized constant ApplicationController::CanCan (NameError)
from /home/dexter/Desktop item/Triton/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ckeditor-4.0.4/app/controllers/ckeditor/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:434:in `eager_load!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/dexter/Desktop item/Triton/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/dexter/Desktop item/Triton/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from /home/dexter/Desktop item/Triton/config.ru:in `new'
from /home/dexter/Desktop item/Triton/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

My application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :authenticate_user!


  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] = exception.message
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
  def stored_location_for(resource_or_scope)
    nil
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    '/dashboard'
  end



end
```

Gemfile > just posted the place of CanCan

```
group :assets do
  gem 'cancan'

end
```

Comment: Please, show us your application controller and gemfile.

Comment: Cancan should not belong in your assets group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove cancan from your assets group in your Gemfile.  The assets group are gems that are not to be used in production.  Therefore when you run the application in production mode,  gems in the assets block will be excluded.

Comment: where it should be ? , i put it under `gem 'rails'` but its the same

Comment: hey , i moved `gem 'cancan'` and `gem 'devise'` from the assets to be under `gem 'rails'` and it works , thank you :)) now i should make `rake db:migrate` , am i right ?

Comment: You should 'bundle install'